# How to read Map inside a Dataset in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a nested JSON format for instance

```
{
  "id": 5,
  "obj": {
    "x": 5
  }
}
```

and I'd like to interpret it as `(Int, Map[String, AnyRef])` or even better as

```
case class MyRow(id: Int, obj: Map[String, AnyRef])
```

I bet this can be easily achieved in Spark but I don't feel strong enough to tackle it on my own. Tried to use `.as[T]` method of a `DataFrame` by reading the file with `spark.read.json`. Unfortunately map got interpreted as a nested structure and I got a runtime error.

```
df.as[(Int, Map[String, AnyRef])] // this throws runtime exception
```

Clarification: of course number of properties within `obj` vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got this. I'll self-answer it.

First of all, `as[(Int, Map[String, AnyRef])]` didn't work because this format is not a tuple - it's kind of a map.

Unfortunately, I didn't get `MyRow` working because I declared this case class within a method that used it. Scala couldn't infer the encoder for it. That is:

```
def run (spark: SparkSession): Unit = {
  import spark.implicits._

  case class MyRow(id: Int, obj: Map[String, AnyRef])
  val frame = spark.read.json("...").as[MyRow]
// ...
```

couldn't compile but

```
case class MyRow(id: Int, obj: Map[String, AnyRef])
def run (spark: SparkSession): Unit = {
  import spark.implicits._

  val frame = spark.read.json("...").as[MyRow]
// ...
```

works as expected.